# Print closing tags with XMLDOM in VBScript

Tags: xml, vbscript, xmldom

I am using a XMLDOM object in VBScript to read and entire XML file and return all the tags and the values. I am currently able to read all parent and child nodes, but I am not able to find the location of where the parent tag closes. I need to store the xml in an array. This way, if I know the hierarchy and the node values, I can create a new object(not only XML) later on, but when I read the xml I loose the hierarchy of the XML. Is there any way I can do this with XMLDOM?

This prints all Opening Tags:

```
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.Async = "False" 
xmlDoc.Load(Records.xml) 
Set NodeList = xmlDoc.selectNodes ("//")

For Each objNode in NodeList
  value = objNode.nodeName
  msgbox value
Next
```

Sample XML:

```
<Records>
  <Person>
    <First>Jon</First>
    <Last>Doe</Last>
  </Person>
  <Car>
    <Color>Blue</Color>
    <Year>2010</Year>
    <Miles>19000</Miles>
  </Car>
</Records>
```

Current Output:

```
Records
Person
First
Last
Car
Color
Year
Miles
```

Needed Output:

```
Records
Person
First
Last
/Person
Car
Color
Year
Miles
/Car
/Records
```

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What do you think you need the location of the closing tags for? Parsed XML is a hierarchical data structure, so your question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: XML is hierarchical, an array is not. Why do you want an array to 'recreate' the XML? Do you want to modify it? Why not manipulate the DOM and .Save it?